# Triggering a new jenkins build through ansible

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I'm looking for a solution where I want to trigger a Jenkins build through Ansible.

I went through a module called **jenkins_job** from which I can connect to the jenkins server but not able to trigger a new build.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you could use the [`uri_module`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/uri_module.html):

```
- name: Queue build of a project in Jenkins
  uri:
    url: "http://{{ jenkins.host }}/job/{{ jenkins.job }}/build?token={{ jenkins.token }}"
    method: POST
    user: "{{ jenkins.user }}"
    password: "{{ jenkins.password }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    status_code: 201
```

That does use the [Jenkins Remote access API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/jenkins/remote+access+api)

Comment: What will this uri module do? Let me explain clearly my problem. There is a "Build now" button in jenkins API where we'll click on it to trigger the build. I need to run that build through Ansible.

Comment: @Venkatesh It will post a request for Jenkins to run a build, triggering a *new* build, which is what you asked for. Same as clicking on the "Build" button in Jenkins.